# bash script to Ping 1000+ ip at the same time via loop

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

LocationDevice array includes all the devices in the location (from a text file)

what I want to do is to to save the statistics results in the PingValue[$k] array and to print them out in the next loop (it will be something other than printing of course) I want to find away to do send the declaration command to the background so the 1000 devices pings happen for less than 10 seconds  (-c 5 for each device) then i get to call my arrays in process them in the second loop.

I tried to echo `` PingValue[$k]=`ping -c 5 -q ${LocationDevice[$k]}` `` but didn't work and the array didn't have the value and ALL the results printed after couple or seconds

```
for ((k=0;k<${#LocationDevice[@]};k++)) do
PingValue[$k]=`ping -c 5 -q ${LocationDevice[$k]}`
done
sleep 10
for ((i=0;i<${#LocationDevice[@]};i++)) do
echo "${PingValue[$i]}"          
done
```

Comment: I edited the formatting, assume this is what you meant. Please check if it's correct

Comment: You may want to also try asking on serverfault for advice on how to efficiently ping 1000s of servers.

Answer (score 1):

Combining the output from multiple parallel background processes into a single array is tricky because those processes can't easily access any shared memory. The best way, I think, is to build a large pipeline to synchronize the data and to use a null value to delineate the output from each process. The best way to launch such a pipeline is recursively. However there won't be any way to quickly read 1000 results from the pipeline into the final array, that takes a while. Instead you can do your processing as you read each item from the pipeline (while building the array if you still need it after). Try this:

```
PingHosts() {
        [ "$1" ] || return
        host="$1"; shift
        rest=("$@")
        (
                r=$(ping -c 5 -q "$host")
                echo "$r"
                printf "\0"
                cat
        ) < <(PingHosts "${rest[@]}" &)
}

for ((i=0; i<${#LocationDevice[@]}; ++i)) do
        read -r -d $'\0' pingresult
        PingValue[$i]="$pingresult"

        echo "Processing result for $i:"
        echo "${PingValue[$i]}"
        echo "-----------------------"
done < <(PingHosts "${LocationDevice[@]}")
```

Comment: Just tried it for a list of 550 devices. so couple of things happened
1. it took so long for the loop to print out all the results, 10+ minutes and I had to kill it before it finished, reached 500 almost
2. the process kept consuming memory, took about 11 GB and the problem is even after I killed it the memory did not flush and the 11GB still appear as being used in htop.
3. The server running on a vm with 4 CPUs and 16 GB mem, CPUs were  utilized between 30-60 percent each,

Unfortunately  this is  too long for us and it's consuming too much resources for just pinging the devices

Comment: @JosephFY it's most likely just that your system just  can't handle launching 500 parallel processes. That's pretty extreme. I forgot to mention it because it wasn't your question.

Comment: and what about that the memory is still being reserved by these processes even after the script was killed/finished ?
I still hope that someone else may have different idea to do so, the goal is to ping 5000+ devices in a considerably accepted timely manner !!

Comment: @JosephFY hmm, well it definitely shouldn't​ have done that. I only tested this with a dozen though. I will try tomorrow with a larger number to see what I get. But as I said, launching hundreds of parallel processes might not be viable regardless of how you try to collect the results. You might need to settle for a dozen or so at a time.

Comment: did you get a chance to look at the the memory being filled up issue ?